# Laravel: generate route without subdomain

Tags: php, laravel

I've got multiple subdomains. On each of them I've got the same navbar. In navbar there is a link:

```
<li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
```

but, when clicked, it redirects to /register url on subdomain - it should redirect to /register url on main domain. How can I do it?

Routes:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{shop}.example.org'], function () {
Route::get('/', 'ShopController@show');
});

Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: can show us the routes in routes file?

Comment: sure, added to question

Comment: Where is it :p ??

Comment: okay, now it is :P

Comment: ok first of all I don't see the register route here so I assume you defined it using Auth::routes(); then I should tell you its probably because the route does not have the name('register') or you should take the Auth::routes() and place it before Route:group .... part? does that help?

Comment: the other suggestion is to use url('/register') instead of Routes('register'); as mentioned in here :https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-route

Comment: It was much time since I posted. Okay, so I tried using /register, but it throws Route [/register] not defined